# Booleen check in C#; converting code

Tags: c#, boolean, int

If found this bit of code:

```
int error;
if (error > 0)
{
    if (error || (move_y > 0))
    {
        los_x_1 += move_x;
        error -= delta_y;
    }
}
```

here: http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Another_version_of_BLA

I thought the code was in C# but the above block of code is not working; I am thinking that it is checking it to see if 'error == 1' but I am not sure.  Any ideas?

Comment: I did not try to compile this code, but IMHO it is not valid C#. `error` is an `int`, not a `bool`, so the logical `OR` operator should refuse to be applied to it and `move_y > 0`.

Comment: Looks to me as if it could be javascript.

Comment: @Lee - error is treated as a boolean right after that as well.

Comment: @Jeffery, not with `int`, no.

Comment: @JefferyKhan - Yes, if this was C# the code wouldn't compile for a couple of reasons. However, it looks like the question is about which language this actually is given it compiles, so it's probably C or C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's likely to be C (or C++), where "any non-zero value" is deemed as "true" for Boolean constructs. So the C# would be:

```
int error;
...
if (error > 0)
{
    if (error != 0 || (move_y > 0))
    {
        los_x_1 += move_x;
        error -= delta_y;
    }
}
```

However, as this is already within `if (error > 0)` it's pointless as the condition will *always* be true - the code is effectively:

```
if (error > 0)
{
    los_x_1 += move_x;
    error -= delta_y;
}
```

(EDIT: That's not to say the code is *correct* of course... just showing what it actually *does* at the moment.)

Comment: Also _use of uninitialized variable_ will result from the original code?

Comment: regarding equivalent code: what about `(move_y > 0)`, you if pass `if (error > 0)` even `move_y` is negative value

Comment: Thanks, the asking the same questions twice was what was throwing me off.

Comment: Actually `move_y > 0` is never executed; it's always short-circuited because `error != 0` is _always_ true at this point. (likely this is either a transcribing mistake of Anthony where it should be `&&` not `||` or an actual logical bug in the original code) EDIT: I agree though, _most likely_ the intent was `move_y` to be factored in somehow though I'm not positive if it should be when `error > 0 && move_y > 0` or `error > 0 || move_y > 0`. Jon was merely mentioning what the _effective_ code is based on what was posted and how it would actually execute.

Comment: I tested the code all three ways and it should be: 'if (error > 0 || move_y > 0)' -- thanks again for the help.  The comments above also helped me.

Answer (score 3):

This code is in C/C++.  In C#, you cannot implicitly cast an `int` to boolean.  You can however change the `if` statement to check `if ((error != 0) || (move_y) > 0)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably c or c++.

In these (any many other languages), integers can be interpreted as boolean values, where 0 is `false` and any other value is `true`

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, that would be the same as:

```
int error;
if (error > 0)
{
    if (error !=0  || (move_y > 0))
    {
        los_x_1 += move_x;
        error -= delta_y;
    }
}
```

Then again, there is no definition I see for `los_x_1`

Answer (score 0):

It's in C. The `<syntaxhighlight lang="c">` in the page source makes that clear.

What they mean by the nested `if` is beyond me. If `(error > 0)` in the outer `if` is true, then the condition in the nested `if` is always true, too.